# Start VLC command line but not successful stream

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, streaming, tv

Hi i used this code worked with my old tv-tuner (it connected direct with my PC and i used tv digital for streaming.

```
Start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" dvb-t://frequency=522000000:bandwidth=0  :dvb-adapter=0 :live-caching=300 :sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=239.255.1.1,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1},dst=display} :sout-keep
```

Now i just changed to new tv tuner model and directly connected to my network. I have successful stream by manually key all the parameter but not work with my command line code. It started by not streaming.

```
Start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" http://User:4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b@192.168.165.9:80/basicauth/TVC/Preview?channel=i1:DDvbT2:f522000:mofdm:N8894:T3:S6:P0:E3:b8000:a1;-1;0:q99:Q2000:nCNA+%28HD%29&profile=&stid=2019045506 :sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=239.255.1.1,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1},dst=display} :sout-keep
```

Please someone help me!! :(
P.S: im using bat file for executing the script

Answer (score 0):

Read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). There are some characters in your `vlc` command line that should be escaped to be taken literally. Unfortunately, there are different parsing and escaping rules:

- from a batch script:

  - `&` to `^&` (ampersand: use standard escape character *caret* `^`);
  - `%` to `%%` (double any percent sign);
- from command line:

  - `&` to `^&` (ampersand: use standard escape character *caret* `^`);
  - `%` to `^%` (percent sign: use standard escape character *caret* `^` as well).

For better readability, consider merely this *substring* excerpted from your command line (containing both `&` and `%` that should be escaped):

```
"vlc" substring :nCNA+%28HD%29&profile=&stid=2019045506
::to be escaped       %    %  &        &
```

Then, to escape special characters: in command line, use:

```
"vlc" substring :nCNA+^%28HD^%29^&profile=^&stid=2019045506
::      escaped       ^%    ^%  ^&        ^&
```

In a batch script, use:

```
"vlc" substring :nCNA+%%28HD%%29^&profile=^&stid=2019045506
::      escaped       %%    %%  ^&        ^&
```

IMHO you need not to use `start "" ...` command; if necessary, add more `%%` and `^^`... Next batch script line *should* work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" http://User:4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b@192.168.165.9:80/basicauth/TVC/Preview?channel=i1:DDvbT2:f522000:mofdm:N8894:T3:S6:P0:E3:b8000:a1;-1;0:q99:Q2000:nCNA+%%28HD%%29^&profile=^&stid=2019045506 :sout=#duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=239.255.1.1,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1},dst=display} :sout-keep
```

Read next StackOverflow question and answers: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/3439404)